# How to implement USING statement (disposal) in HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code, I would need make sure that HttpWebRequest it is always disposed.

How should I modify my code?

```
  private static void CheckIsConnectedToInternet()
    {
        string urlToCheck = utility.GetConfiguration("device", "checkInternetUrl");
        int timeOut = Convert.ToInt32(utility.GetConfiguration("device", "checkInternetTimeOurMs"));

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToCheck);
        webRequest.Timeout = timeOut;

        // Init your request...then:
        DoWithResponse(webRequest, (response) =>
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                isConnectedToInternet = true;
            else
                isConnectedToInternet = false;
        });
    }

    private static void DoWithResponse(HttpWebRequest request, Action<HttpWebResponse> responseAction)
    {
        Action wrapperAction = () =>
        {
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((iar) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = (HttpWebResponse)((HttpWebRequest)iar.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(iar);
                    responseAction(response);
                }
                catch
                {
                    isConnectedToInternet = false;
                }

            }), request);
        };
        wrapperAction.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback((iar) =>
        {
            var action = (Action)iar.AsyncState;
            action.EndInvoke(iar);
        }), wrapperAction);
    }
```

Comment: HttpWebRequest does not implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the `using() {}` syntax the class must implement IDisposable.

As HttpWebRequest does not implement IDisposable unfortunately you are out of luck on this one!